# how can I get filenames without directory name

Tags: python

how can I list only file names in a directory without directory info in the result? I tried

```
for file in glob.glob(dir+filetype):
    print file
```

give me result
`/path_name/1.log,/path_name/2.log,....`
but what I do need is file name only: `1.log`, `2.log`, etc. I do not need the directory info in the result.  is there a simple way to get rid of the path info? I don't want to some substr on the result. Thank you!

Comment: `dir` is a built-in function, `dir()`. You should choose another variable name in case any of your modules use the function, as it could lead to confusing bugs.

Comment: thank you timss for pointing out this

Comment: And likewise, as @timss points out in a comment to his own answer, you shouldn't use `file` either, as it's the name of a builtin type (and therefore also callable as a function, which works just like `open`).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[`os.path.basename`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename):

> Return the base name of pathname `path`. This is the second element of the pair returned by passing `path` to the function `split()`. Note that the result of this function is different from the Unix `basename` program; where `basename` for '/foo/bar/' returns 'bar', the `basename()` function returns an empty string ('').

So:

```
>>> os.path.basename('/path_name/1.log,/path_name/2.log')
'2.log'
```

Comment: thank you. I applied os.path.basename on the result like this: for file in glob.glob(adir+filetype):
    print os.path.basename (file)   I get what I expected.

Comment: Not to sound annoyed or anything, but I genuinely wonder why this is the most popular answer. How is `glob.glob` and `os.path.basename` better than the simple `os.listdir`? `os.listdir` strikes me as more flexible, especially since it'll give you a list right away, which is probably what you want in most cases. Maybe most people don't like [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

Comment: @timss: The OP specifically wants to get only the files that match a glob-style wildcard expression. Sure, he could use `listdir` plus `fnmatch`, or rethink his code (or possibly even his user interface) so he has some other rule instead of a glob-style wildcard expression… but why? That's exactly what `glob` is for.

Comment: @abarnert Aye, thanks for answering my silly question. I somehow forgot to consider the posibility that OP might use a wildcard expression, and not a simple path.

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

# Do not use 'dir' as a variable name, as it's a built-in function
directory = "path"
filetype  = "*.log"

# ['foo.log', 'bar.log']
[f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith(filetype[1:])]
```

Comment: Presumably he's got a string `filetype="*.log"`, so you need to do `file.endswith(filetype[1:])` or something… and hope that's the only kinds of glob pattern you ever get. (Also, you have to spell the methods right.)

Comment: Of course, but OP doesn't say anything about the use of a filetype variable being final, just how to list all files in a directory with a given filetype without full path. Thanks for pointing out the spelling error.

Comment: Well, you have to assume that his code represents what he's trying to do, especially given that his code apparently already works, other than returning paths instead of just filenames.

Comment: Fair point. I updated my answer (and changed `file` with `f` to not overwrite `class file(object)`

Comment: Definitely a good change, but a tiny nitpick on the comment: `file` isn't defined as `class file(object)`, it's a separate builtin `type`. It isn't even a subclass of `object` (although `isinstance(x, object)` is guaranteed true for any `type` instance, etc., so that rarely makes any difference). And to be even more nitpicky, builtin `type`s aren't literally `class`es at all (but even the documentation and source code are inconsistent about that distinction…). Anyway, as I said, nice change.

Comment: I used `help(file)` in the python interactive interpreter to check this, and it's defined as `class file(object)`. Oddly enough I can't seem to find the exact documentation on docs.python.org. Do you know the reasoning behind this, and if maybe it is indeed correct that is `class file(object)` as defined by `help(file)`?

Comment: Well, the `help` is written separately from the code. In CPython 2.x, a `file` is a wrapper around a `PyFile *` (as defined [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c)). There's no actual inheritance… but since `object` has no non-default method slots, the `help` system adds the `class foo(object)` for any builtin type that doesn't say otherwise, and `isinstance` and `subclass` treat any `type` as if it were a subclass of `object`, I guess it is correct as far as any reasonable attempt to detect it from within Python. Is that good enough?

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. It's easy to get confused if you don't know the quirks behind `help()` and the implementation of the built-ins.

Comment: It's actually a fair question which one of us was "confused", or maybe we both were, or neither. The language is a little ambiguous in a few areas (and the CPython implementation doesn't really prove anything except about the CPython implementation).

Comment: Aye, atleast we can conclude that using `file` (or `dir`) as variable names is a bad idea eitehr way. Some editors will point this out for you too, for example in vim it'll get the color of a built-in type/function, so it's pretty easy to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
import os
[file.rsplit(os.path.sep, 1)[1] for file in glob.glob(dir+filetype)]
```

Comment: Don't you want `[-1]` instead?

Comment: Sure, but is there a difference ? Just curious

Comment: I take it back, didn't notice it was `rsplit` which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: The whole reason for `os.path` is that you shouldn't try to do pathname manipulation in terms of string manipulation, because it's harder to read, easier to get wrong, and more likely to confuse other readers (as happened with Mark Ransom). Also, this is presumably the kind of thing the OP meant by "I don't want to some substr on the result".